# NextJS Next-auth wrong redirection with next-intl

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

in my app, i am using next-auth to protect all pages and i need also to set a custom login page.

The page work well but for some reason i get correctly redirected only the first time to the custom page with locale prefix.

```
  // in ....src\pages\api\auth\[...nextauth].js
pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
  },

and my custom page template in ....\src\pages\auth\signin.js
```

Navigation example:

After landing to home page or any protected page ->  redirect to :

```
/auth/signin?callbackUrl=.....
```

LInk above is working with default locale.

From that page (/auth/signin) if i switch language using dropdown menu for locales still work well

```
en/auth/signin?......  // en as prefix of lang selected
```

Click on any link from that page , i get redirect again here but without locale prefix but with an expected prefix as /api/ instead locale prefix

```
/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=%2Fabout
```

It cause the missing locale file preload, and if i use the dropdown to change language nothing change (redirected but with same URL and no locale prefix).

At the moment i cant figure out how to manage a proper redirection with locale missin part.

Thank you

Comment: At the moment to avoid the problem, i am using a Client side to wrap the protected pages + a custom login page not protected without next-auth custom page configuration.

Comment: You might be interested in this thread: https://github.com/amannn/next-intl/issues/247. Proper documentation for this use case is coming! :)

Comment: We now have docs and an example for NextAuth: https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/next-13/middleware#example-auth-js

Comment: The example does not work. It can only have multiple languages in public pages. Protected pages can only have default language. Middleware: if (isPublicPage) {
    return intlMiddleware(req);
  } else {
    return (authMiddleware as any)(req);
  }